# Run fsck_hfs on firewire volume that won't mount

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a disk in a firewire bay which shows up in Disk Utility but does not mount because a RAID enclosure messed up the format. If the disk is not mounted how can I reference it in command-line to run fsck_hfs on it?

Answer (score 0):

Unforunatly, I haven't found the way to do in in osx.
However, the best thing to do (that worked for me) is to boot Hirens boot cd* and check it with some of the filesystem tools (Ext2fsd was used in my case).

Hope this was useful :)

- http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd